# Api gateway, Service Regisry and Service Mesh, how they work togather?

Tags: microservices, reverse-proxy, service-discovery, api-gateway

What I know so far is that:

1. **Api gateway**: Is fixed entry point that manage north/south communications.
2. **Service Mesh**: Is a side-car proxy that manage inter-service communication east/west.
3. **service registry**: Is a database of services, their instances and their locations.

All sound clear, but when I try to put all things together, I am  confused:

- Most of the service mesh/api gateway vendors say that they provide
  access control mechanisms and other similar mechanisms, are these mechanisms an overlapping
  functionalities between both concepts, or they have different scope
  and goals?

Assume all Api gateway, Service Mesh and Service registry are deployed together:

- Does the api gateway forward the request directly to the service, or
  it communicate with service proxy?
- Do I have to register a service twice, one in the gateway and one in
  the service registry? or how to integrate the service registy  with api gateway?

Finally Until now it seems for me the all concepts purely serve different purposes so they all necessary, but they overloaded with other functionalities. Is it possible to integrate them in meaningful way? or is there a reference architecture that I can follow?

Answer (score 0):

Because no one posted an answer and based on my continuous reading, I was able to grasp a basic idea of how all components should work together, I will not answer directly to question, rather I will try to make things more clear:

> *API Gateway* or *Service Mesh* are nothing just **proxies**, but with that said they are proxies of different types.

API Gateway is a **front-proxy** or **edge-proxy**, through it you communicate with the world. so in your architecture you may have an API Gateway running with or without Service Mesh beeing deployed.

To register your services in your Gateway you have two options(maybe more):

- Static registration: using configuration file or using the Admin API of the API Gateway you are using, this is similar of how KONG work.
- Dynamic registration: usually this is done by integrating your Front-proxy (API Gateway) with some other **Service Registry/Discovery** tool. you can [accomplish that](https://www.envoyproxy.io/learn/service-discovery) for example using Envoy and consul.io.

Using only Front-proxy (without service mesh) It is hard to do health monitoring, Logging and let all service know if it’s pointless to try to contact a down service(Circuit breaker).

Now, if you need to isolate your services from the topology of the network, or you need to provide a set of functionality around each of your services such as, mentoring, Logging, retries, circuit breaker..etc, then you can accomplish that by deploying a process (beside each service) that proxies all the out and in requests to your service. This process what we call a **sidecar proxy**. All the sidecars proxies usually run the same code, but they are configured differently.

Finally: The **combination** of the edge-proxy (API Gateway ) and the sidecar proxies forms what we call a **Service Mesh**. And obviously all proxies can utilize the same service registry/discovery mechanism.